# prevent custom text to increase plot size

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am writing some text on my plot, which works perfectly fine. Now I realized that if I put the text further down the y-axis, the plot space somehow becomes larger. This is not what I want. The following 2 plots illustrate the issue. The first one puts the text at y = 0, whereas the second one puts it at y = the min-0.25, so roughly where the plot space begins vertically. Is it possible to keep the plot space as in the first plot, but still to write at the bottom? If there is no intended way to adjust that, I would also be happy with a workaround.

```
set.seed(12)
test <- data.table(x = rnorm(29*2),var=c(rep("x1",29),rep("x2",29)),
                   time=rep(seq(as.Date("1983/12/31"),as.Date("2011/12/31"), "year"),2))
library(ggplot2);library(scales)
ggplot(data=test,aes(x=time, y=x, colour=var)) +
  geom_line() + scale_x_date(date_labels="%Y",date_breaks = "3 years") +
  geom_text(aes(x=as.Date("1988-04-30"), label="Text which does not increases space", y=0,
                fontface="plain"), angle=60, colour="black",vjust=0,hjust=0,size = 4)

ggplot(data=test,aes(x=time, y=x, colour=var)) +
  geom_line() + scale_x_date(date_labels="%Y",date_breaks = "3 years") +
  geom_text(aes(x=as.Date("1988-04-30"), label="Text which increases space", y=min(test[,x])-0.25,
                fontface="plain"), angle=60, colour="black",vjust=0,hjust=0,size = 4)
```

Comment: Can you include the variable `textcol` in your code?  Also, I think you mean to have the function `data.frame`, not `data.table` in line 2.

Comment: @AmadouKone sorry, fixed. Code works now. datatable inherits from dataframe, so it can be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As any other geom, `geom_text` expands the plotting area in cases like this. Then it's necessary to manually restrict the y axis with `ylim(range(test$x))`. However, that's not enough, as then the text wouldn't be fully visible and, as a result, `ggplot` completely drops it. To fix this, we need `clip = "off"`. Thus, adding

```
coord_cartesian(clip = "off", ylim = range(test$x))
```

gives

[image]

where now axes are unchanged.

Comment: indeed that's what it does. Thank you, great sol!